# Counting strongly connected components in a directed graph in $NL$

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, space-complexity, computation-models, nondeterminism

Define $K\_SCC = \{ \langle G, k \rangle \,:\, G \text{ has at least $k$ strongly connected components} \}$

I want to show that $K\_SCC \in NSPACE(\log n)$, using that $st-CONN$ and $\overline{st-CONN}$ are both in NL, where $st-CONN = \{\langle G,s,t \rangle \,:\, \text{there is a path from $s$ to $t$ in $G$} \}$.

Would appreciate any help

Comment: Any strongly connected component $C$ is uniquely represented by the vertex $x\in C$ that has the smallest numerical label. Show that you can recognize such vertices in NL, and then you can just count them in increasing order.

Answer (score -2):

Ask the prover to give you any node from $k$ distinct connected components.

You have only to verify that the nodes are not in the same connected components (hence, they are in $k$ different components, meaning that $\langle G, k\rangle \in K_{SCC}$)

Also, ask for the proof of $st-CON$ between any two of them.

Notice that even though the proof is gigantic, at every point in time the verifier will need to only verify a small portion of the proof: only one $st-CON$ is being processed at a time, hence the verifier can be constructed in such a way that will require only $O(\log(n))$ space.

The pseudocode for the verifier should look similar to this:

- For every $i\neq j$ with $1\le i,j\le k$, do:

  - Take a look at the next $O(\log(n))$ bits of proof, and verify $st-CON$ for the $i$'th and the $j$'th nodes

Comment: As the question is stated, $k$ is not constant. It is part of the input.

Comment: Oops :p I totally missed this important thing...

Comment: When I think about it, since at every point in time the verifier only checks one $ST-con$ proof of size $O(\log(n))$, then the verifier can just check the proofs one by one in some predefined order, and the verifier wont use more than $O(\log(n))$ space. Yes, the proof is larger, but if I remember correctly thats allowed for as long as the verifier requires small space.

Comment: This is true except for how you specify which $k$ nodes you want to show are in different components. This will take $O(k\log(n))$ memory, which is not logarithmic in the size of $k$...

Comment: The definition of NL does not allow you to generate a polynomial-size “proof” and subsequently verify it in logarithmic space. This would in fact give you all of NP. See my comment below the question how to do this correctly.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek  think it does allow it, for as long as its written in a "read-once" tape, and the verifier works with logarithmic space

Comment: Your verifier is not “read once”. Since you need to compare each node with each other, you need to read each one $k$ times.

Comment: No, you ask the prover to give you one proof for every $i\neq j$. Its actually $k \choose 2$ proofs, but you can treat each one seperately. If you define beforehand on how you will iterate all $i$ and $j$, then this can be done with a "read once" tape.

Comment: No, you can’t do that, because then there would be no guarantee that the supposed proofs for the pairs $(i,j)$ and $(i,j')$ really use the same node as the “$i$th node”. Look, what you are trying to do is no different from claiming that SAT is in NL because you can give as a witness a satisfying assignment, arranged as a list of Boolean values for each variable occurrence in the input CNF in the order that they appear. This cannot work.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I agree with you, and I have already written that: "This is true except for how you specify which $k$ nodes you want to show are in different components". If you knew that, then you can be sure that $(i,j)$ and $(i,j')$ really use the same $i$'th node, by literally verifying that it is that $i$'th node. What you said about 3SAT is actually concerning me, so I will think more about this. I probably missed something somewhere...